PHP. Вывести массив после авторизации
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx");

if($conn->connect_error){
   die("#4: " . $conn->connect_error);
}else{
   
$login = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['login']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE login = '$login' and password = '$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
echo $result;
   
}

?>```


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

#2 Yo have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaBD server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1(null)

Здесь всё очень плохо, начиная с того, что этот код не может выдать такую ошибку. Так что я просто дам ссылку на правильный код
